# Remove specific application from Data usage

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, data-monitoring

I'm using Marshmallow and I'm rooted.

After looking in alot of places and search in google I didn't find any answer.

My question is, is possible to remove specific information in Data Usage in android?
For exemple I have 1Gb of net to use monthly but my carrier don't count if I am using Instagram. Can I remove Instagram for data usage?

Thanks

Comment: I have a better suggestion. Use Opera Max, available on Play Store. It shows usage for each app, can restrict access to Wi-Fi or data for certain apps, and can even compress data to save money.

Comment: This is not my goal. My goal is still using the app, but I want that shouldn't appear in data usage.

Comment: You have to do it manually.